# How does the Domain (DNS) hierarchy work? Sub-domain Vs SLD

Tags: dns, domain, domain-name, subdomain

I was reading some text online and noticed the resource refer to `dir2.website1.com` as third level domain. While we usually refer to `dir2` as being subdomain of `website1`. And also `website1.com` should technically be called a second level domain but we loosely refer to as just a domain. Now I am getting quite confused with the whole thing. Please asses below statements:

1. Calling `website1.com` a second level domain is correct.
2. `website1.com` is also referred to as just a domain however technically incorrect.
3. Calling `dir2.website1.com` a third level domain is technically correct.
4. `dir2.website1.com` is also referred to as subdomain.

Also registrar offer registration to suffix like `ca.us` or `edu.in` in such cases does the above terminology change or remains the same. For e.g.

1. `website1.ca.us` is technically a third level domain registered under a 2nd level suffix.
2. In `dir2.website1.ca.us` the `dir2` is however refer to as subdomain of `website1` but is technically a 4th level domain overall.

OR

3. In `dir2.website1.ca.us` the `website1.ca.us` remains the 2nd level domain and  `dir2.website1.ca.us` remains third level domain.

Please correct me wherever I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for technical correctness, then [RFC 8499: DNS Terminology](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8499) is relevant – together with [RFC 1034: Domain names - Concepts and facilities](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034). (Though even with that, this still remains a somewhat subjective question.)

- It seems there is a slight difference between a "domain" (administrative unit containing hosts and sites) and a "domain name" (its representation in DNS containing addresses and records).
- The terminology does not inherently require specifying which level a domain name is at. Calling a domain "a domain" is equally as correct as calling it "a second-level domain".

  It is less *precise*, of course, but that does not make it incorrect. You can still call a blue car "a car" and be correct, no matter how blue it is.
- A subdomain is still a domain. According to RFC 8499, the term "subdomain" describes the *relationship* between two domains, rather than a specific domain – e.g. "dir2.website1.com" is a subdomain *of* the "website1.com" domain, but that doesn't stop it from also being a domain in itself.

  Similarly, the domain "website1.com" is a subdomain of the "com" top-level domain, and of the "" root domain.
- Generally, domain name levels are determined by their representation in DNS, *not* by their management. A domain name such as `dir2.website1.ca.us` consists of four components ("labels"), making it a 4th-level domain.

  Second-level domains which practically act like top-level domains, such as `co.uk` or `ac.au`, are sometimes called "effective TLD" or "eTLD". The immediate next level (4th-level or higher domains which are registered like 2nd-level domains) is commonly referred to as "eTLD+1". So `co.uk` is an an eTLD in web, but a second-level domain in DNS.

  In web contexts, the term "eTLD" is a synonym for "public suffix" and also includes domains which don't *quite* act as TLDs, such as `eu.org` and `dyndns.org`. This is especially necessary among web browsers when dealing with cookies across domain boundaries. (Browsers use a huge "public suffix list" to make the decision.)